# I cannot use context.canvas.height when testing against the position of an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have made a simple rocket with controls and I want it to stop when it hits the ground but for whatever reason the only number that I can use to test it against is 0. I have tried context.canvas.height - this.size.height because that is what I want it to be, but when I use that in the if statement the code does not work as desired. The goal is to be able to stop all of the rocket's movement when it hits the ground.
Here is my JavaScript code

```
(function () {

    //  the canvas constants
    const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //  setting the canvas size
    context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    //  the game constants
    const ROCKET_SIZE = { width: 20, height: 30 };
    const ROCKET_POSITION = { x: 200, y: 200 };
    const GRAVITY = 2;
    const THRUST = 5;
    const AFTERBURNER_THRUST = 20;
    const INERTIAL_DAMPING = 0.98;

    //  the rocket ship class
    class RocketShip {
        constructor(size, position) {
            this.color = 'white';
            this.size = size;
            this.position = position;
            this.angle = 0;
            this.engineOn = false;
            this.afterburner = false;
            this.inertialDampeners = false;
            this.rotatingLeft = false;
            this.rotatingRight = false;
            this.velocity = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
            };
        }

        draw() {

            //  the center of the rocket
            const triangleCenterX = this.position.x + 0.5 * this.size.width;
            const triangleCenterY = this.position.y + 0.5 * this.size.height;

            context.save();
            context.translate(triangleCenterX, triangleCenterY);
            context.rotate(this.angle);
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.beginPath();

            //  drawing the delta rocket
            context.moveTo(0, -this.size.height / 2);
            context.lineTo(-this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
            context.lineTo(this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
            context.closePath();

            context.strokeStyle = this.color;
            context.stroke();

            //  drawing the engine if it is active
            if (this.engineOn) {
                const fireYPos = this.size.height / 2 + 5;
                const fireXPos = this.size.width * 0.25;
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.lineTo(fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.lineTo(0, fireYPos + Math.random() * 50);
                context.lineTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle = 'orange';
                context.fill();
            }

            //  drawing the afterburner if it is active
            if (this.afterburner) {

                const fireYPos = this.size.height / 2 + 5;
                const fireXPos = this.size.width * 0.25;
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.lineTo(fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.lineTo(0, fireYPos + Math.random() * 100);
                context.lineTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle = 'red';
                context.fill();
            }

            context.restore();
        }

        moveRocket() {

            // convert angle from degrees to radians
            const degToRad = Math.PI / 180;

            //  changing the position of the rocket
            this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
            this.position.y += this.velocity.y;

            //  moving the rocket to the other side of the screen
            if (this.position.x > context.canvas.width) {
                this.position.x = 0;
            }
            if (this.position.x < 0) {
                this.position.x = context.canvas.width;
            }
            if (this.position.y > context.canvas.height) {
                this.position.y = 0;
            }
            if (this.position.y < 0) {
                this.position.y = context.canvas.height;
            }

            //  stopping the rocket if it hits the ground
            if (this.position.y === context.canvas.height - this.size.height) {
                this.velocity.y = -GRAVITY / 100;
                this.velocity.x = 0;
            }

            //  turning the rocket
            if (this.rotatingLeft) {
                this.angle -= degToRad;
            }
            if (this.rotatingRight) {
                this.angle += degToRad;
            }

            //  accelerating the rocket if the thrust is on
            if (this.engineOn) {
                this.velocity.x += (THRUST / 100) * Math.sin(this.angle);
                this.velocity.y -= (THRUST / 100) * Math.cos(this.angle);
            }

            //  accelerating the rocket if the afterburner is on
            if (this.afterburner) {
                this.velocity.x += (AFTERBURNER_THRUST / 100) * Math.sin(this.angle);
                this.velocity.y -= (AFTERBURNER_THRUST / 100) * Math.cos(this.angle);
            }

            //  decelerating the rocket if the inertial dampeners are on
            if (this.inertialDampeners) {
                this.velocity.x *= INERTIAL_DAMPING;
                this.velocity.y *= INERTIAL_DAMPING;
            }

            //  updating the rocket's velocity due to gravity
            this.velocity.y += GRAVITY / 100;
        }
    }

    const rocket = new RocketShip(ROCKET_SIZE, ROCKET_POSITION);

    //  handling the keyboard events
    function handleKeyInput(event) {
        const { keyCode, type } = event;
        const isKeyDown = type === 'keydown';

        if (keyCode === 37) {
            rocket.rotatingLeft = isKeyDown;
        }
        if (keyCode === 39) {
            rocket.rotatingRight = isKeyDown;
        }
        if (keyCode === 38) {
            rocket.engineOn = isKeyDown;
        }
        if (keyCode === 32) {
            rocket.afterburner = isKeyDown;
        }
        if (keyCode === 40) {
            rocket.inertialDampeners = isKeyDown;
        }
    }

    //  resizing the screen
    function onResize() {
        context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function draw() {

        //  drawing space
        context.fillStyle = '#111';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        rocket.moveRocket();

        //  drawing the rocket
        rocket.draw();

        //  repeating the draw function
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    //  adding event listeners to the webpage
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyInput);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyInput);
    document.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

    //  starting the game
    draw();
})();
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rocket</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="styles/rocket2.css"  >
</head>
<body id="body">

    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
    <script src="pscripts/rocket/rocket.js"></script>

    <button class="info-btn">
        Hello World
    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #111;
}

#game {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.info-btn {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2vh;
    right: 2vw;
    color: white;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    font-size: 2vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info-btn:hover {
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    color: #c7c7c7;
}

.info {
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
}
```

The code that I have been trying to use to stop the rocket when it reaches context.canvas.height - this.size.height is:

```
if (this.position.y === context.canvas.height - this.size.height) {
                this.velocity.y = -GRAVITY / 100;
                this.velocity.x = 0;
}
```

I am trying to check if the y position of the rocket is equal to the canvas height - the height of the rocket and if so I set the y velocity to the opposite of gravity over 100 so that it has no movement and I set the x velocity to 0.

Thank you to anyone who reads this and tries to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `===` your code will only work when they are equal which is almost never going to happen in an animation. The object could pass the given point between frames. You should use `>=`

```
if (this.position.y >= context.canvas.height - this.size.height) {
                this.velocity.y = -GRAVITY / 100;
                this.velocity.x = 0;
            }
```